# DOMpdf on server

Tags: webserver, dompdf

I have DOMpdf installed on my localhost (WAMP & dompdf downloaded from git) and it works fine. Installation was done using composer. When I installed in on my localhost, there was a subdirectory called DOMpdf.

I had it installed on the webserver by running the command "apt install php-dompdf" it installed fine and server restarted. But doesn't work, I mean in the console it has the error

```
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"
```

I found where the config file is stored on the webserver and changed the location in my php file accordingly to

```
require_once("/etc/php-dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
```

As a result I got different error messages.

```
[Mon Oct 30 16:50:40.500977 2023] [php7:error] [pid 3532633] [client 10.64.4.168:64880] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function DOMPDF::stream(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/nztimesheets/testDOMpdf.php on line 29 and at least 1 expected in /usr/share/php/dompdf/include/dompdf.cls.php:1057\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/nztimesheets/testDOMpdf.php(29): DOMPDF->stream()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /usr/share/php/dompdf/include/dompdf.cls.php on line 1057
```

Having searched other threads, I noticed people using autoload.inc.php but that is not an option in my php-dompdf folder.

The php code is:

```
<?php
    echo('Here!');
    
    require_once("/etc/php-dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    
    echo('Here now.');

    use DOMpdf;
    use DOMpdf\options;

    $dompdf=new DOMpdf();

    $html = '<h1 style="color: blue;"> Hello this is from DOM pdf to convert html to pdf<h1>';

    $dompdf->load_html($html);

    $dompdf->set_Paper('A4','landscape');

    $dompdf->render();

    $dompdf->stream();
?>
```

Is there anything obvious as to why it won't work on the server?
(NB: I changed the require_once from my working php file on the localhost for the server)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a filename in the stream() function.

```
$dompdf->stream('myfilename.pdf');
```

In my localhost, it just opened/created the pdf in a browser window.